# Serving static html files to a meteor template using Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've recently set up a meteor website and am really loving how easy it is to build templates from data in my mongo db.

One part of my website I just want to render a static html file in my layout template I've setup. At the moment I have a layout file that looks like this

```
<template name="mainLayout">

    {{> yield region="navBar"}}

    {{> yield}}

    {{> yield region="footer"}}

</template>
```

All I want to do is when I hit a specific route instead of finding a template and filling it with data from the db I just want to insert a static html page into that main part of my layout.

Is this possible or do you have any suggestions on other ways to solve this?

I can't think of a way to standardise what I have in these html files so they all fit one template so its much easier to just serve them as static pages.

Comment: Just render the static template.

Comment: But I can't find how I'm meant to do that. Below is how my current routes look

`this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    layoutTemplate: 'mainLayout',
    yieldTemplates: {
      'navBar': {to: 'navBar'},
      'footer': {to: 'footer'}
    }
  });`

Comment: Just put all the static content in the desired template and render it like always {{>my_template_with_static_content}}. In thiz case 'home'

Comment: Thanks I was thinking of doing that but I have several html files I would like this to work for and it's a bit of a pain in the ass creating different templates for all of them

Comment: Not a paint. Just wrap them in <template name='xxx'> </template> tags

Comment: Yeah good point. I currently have them in my public folder but if I just move them to my client folder and wrap them in template tags that does it for me automatically. Thanks :)